# POWERSHELL 5: Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Form'

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have this code fragment in PowerShell 7

> ```
> Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ("Scan completed!") `n
>
> #3. Export the scan to the FPR format
> $fprurl = 'http://' + $wiAPIurl + '/webinspect/scanner/scans/' + $scanId + '.fpr '
> $path = $scanId + '.fpr'
>
> Write-Host ("Downloading the result file (fpr)...")
> Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Method GET -OutFile $path -uri "$fprurl"
> Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ("Result file (fpr) download done!") `n
>  
> #4. Upload the Results to SSC
> $sscheaders = '@{
>     "Authorization" = "FortifyToken '+ $sscToken + '"
>     "ContentType" = "multipart/form-data"
>     "accept" = "application/json"
> }'
> $sscheader_exp = Invoke-Expression $sscheaders
> $sscuploadurl = $sscURL + 'api/v1/projectVersions/' + $applicationVersionID + '/artifacts'
>
> Write-Host ("Starting Upload to SSC...")
> Invoke-RestMethod -uri $sscuploadurl -Method POST -Headers $sscheader_exp -Form @{file=(Get-Item $path)}
> Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ("Finished! Scan Results are now availible in the Software Security Center!")
> ```

and when I am trying to run it in PowerShell 5 I get the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Form'
```

Find out that the "Form" parameter is not supported in powershell 5.
How could I replace that part of the code to be able to run it?

Comment: use the `-Body` parameter instead